# Why do LEDs cause this delay?

Tags: led

At first, I might suspect from the comparator itself, however having LEDs or not having them makes a difference. So I suspect it might be something related to LED structure.

[image]

**With LEDs connected:**

[image]

*current on LEDs:*

[image]

---

**When I replace LEDs by short circuit:**

[image]

Note: green sine wave has 1 ms period.

Comment: What's the time scale in your simulation?

Comment: @winny green sine wave has 1 ms period.

Comment: Please include that time scale in your plots.

Comment: @winny I am not near my pc right now(mobile), do you still need something to know?, or did you say that just for being more clear? I think knowing the period of sine wave would be enough for understanding. Besides that, i will edit it when I am available.

Comment: For me it’s fine, but think about it next time. I assume your opamp needs pull-up and you are not giving it the minimum current specified. Check the datasheet!

Comment: And by opamp I do of course mean comparator.

Comment: @winny by minimum current what do you mean? I know maximum current but don't know what minimum current refers to. If it is supply current, then it takes its supply from +9v I don't think you refer that.

Comment: You are correct, there is none specified. That short could have damaged it, but apart from that, please add a kohm range pull-up on the output.

Answer (score 3):

Light output is related to the LED current, so you should plot that.

The LEDs conduct very little current with only a volt or so across them, so the voltage approaches the positive rail rather slowly given LED and output capacitance.

If you add a resistor such as 30K from the output to the supply rail you’ll see a cleaner looking waveform, but very little difference to the LED current waveform.

Comment: I have added the LED output current waveform, if I change 220 ohms to 30k then simulation get stucks or finishes but cannot display any data for LED current, giving error. I suspect using LEDs create some problems within LTspice. Please also have a look at this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471846/ltspice-using-led-causes-problems

Comment: That’s not what I said to do.

Comment: yes, sorry I misunderstood, doing what you said made out waveform better. So, since my desire from this circuit is the LED current, I don't have to worry about out wave as long as LED current is a nice square wave. Thanks for the answer.